# How to get input parameter Type using GetMethod?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, system.reflection

Good Afternoon Everyone,
I am trying to dynamically invoke a function by passing its appropriate parameters. 
Let's say the function looks like this:

> public string CreatePerson(Person p)

Object p is received as Json and I want to deserialize it into the appropriate runtime Type depending on the parameter Type so that I can pass it into the Newtonsoft.Json library function JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (jsonReceived).

Below is my code:

```
m = this.GetType().GetMethod(method);
List<object> a = new List<object>();
foreach (var param in m.GetParameters())
{
    //have to convert args parameter to appropriate function input
     a.Add(ProcessProperty(param.Name, param.ParameterType, args));

 }

 object invokeResult = null;
 invokeResult = m.Invoke(this, a.ToArray());


private object ProcessProperty(string propertyName, Type propertyType, string    jsonStringObject)
 {
     if (propertyType.IsClass && !propertyType.Equals(typeof(String)))
      {
          var argumentObject = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyType);
          argumentObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<propertyType>(jsonStringObject);
           return argumentObject;
      }
  }
```

I get the following error :

```
The type or namespace name 'propertyType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Where am I approaching this wrong?
How can I get the parameter Type dynamically during runtime so it can handle types other than Person and be able to pass it to DeserializeObject?

Comment: Why not just use [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStringObject,  propertyType)`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm)

Comment: misread your comment dbc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a runtime System.Type `propertyType` as a type parameter to a generic method. Instead, use the overload of `DeserializeObject` that takes a runtime type:

```
argumentObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStringObject, propertyType);
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that generics are done at compile time and you only know the type at runtime. Essentially the compiler thinks that `propertyType` should be a compiled type and not a variable of type `Type`.

Fortunately there are overloads that will let you do what you want such as [`DeserializeObject(String, Type)`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm)

Use like this:

```
argumentObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStringObject, propertyType);
```

Comment: No problem. You will find that quite often anything generic along these lines has an overload like this. And hopefully you understand a bit more about generics now so you can see why this problem happens and know that you should look for alternatives (like other overloads) if you come across something similar. :)